# Compiling languages on work computer (windows)

Tags: batch-file, windows-vista

so at work I'd like to write a program to move my cursor (like a macro), but I a) don't know what compilers these machines have, and b) don't think I can install a compiler.

So the question is, is there any standalone compilers that exist? Is there a way to check what compilers the machine currently has? Or, can I write a batch program that will move & click the cursor for me?

The machine I'm using is Windows Vista, Business Enterprise.

Oh, and I don't really care which language I have to code in, if you have a compiler suggestion.

Thanks!

EDIT: The problem is, I can't *download* or *install* anything on this computer. My only hope would be a webpage...

Comment: What makes you think you need a compiler to *run* your program?

Comment: adarshr is right, why can't you compile the program on another machine and run it on the work one?

Comment: Take a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: I need to be able to develop it on this computer, because I need to interact with this computers exact interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question:

Here's a link to an online code compiler:
http://compilr.com/

It acn compile the code on their servers, and you can download a file to execute on your computer (in my case, via the java command)

Answer (score 0):

Get Visual Studio Express, it'll let you write programs for Windows and it's free unless you intend to sell your program

[Link to VS](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to write macros for Windows, you might want to check out PowerShell. I don't think it's included with Windows Vista, but it's a free download from Microsoft. If you can't do it with PowerShell, try AutoIT.